# what is the purpose of protected variable and method in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java, could you please tell me - 
"what is the purpose of the protected variable and method in Java".

Thanks in advance.
JP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Take a look at the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
The following table shows the access to members permitted by each modifier.

### Access Levels

```
Modifier    Class  Package  Subclass  World
public      Y      Y        Y         Y
protected   Y      Y        Y         N
no modifier Y      Y        N         N
private     Y      N        N         N
```

So, protected elements in a Java application will be accessible form **subclasses, class itself AND classes in the same package!**, knowing this, you should use `protected` when some methods or attributes of one class needs to be shared around.

- If you don't want any leaking of internal state, then declaring all your member variables private is the way to go.
- If you don't really care that subclasses can access internal state, then protected is good enough.